# Where does Rails get the timezone before converting to the UTC 0 timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

Right now it's 6:25pm EST. Active Record will convert that time to 23:45 UTC 0. How does Rails know what timezone to base that conversion off of? Does it take that from the browser locale or the app server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# application.rb:
class Application < Rails::Application
   config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
#model.rb
t = (Time.now-6.hours).beginning_of_day 
 #Use this method in your model with create and use the different 
 #timing 
 #and it look like -5 not -6 as mine :D
```